# razor view jQuery ajax call - model not fully populated

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have buttons with related jQuery ajax click calls. The model being passed in has some of the fields populated but not all.

The buttons in question are included in the page as a part of a partial.  The partial page looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="adjustScoreModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Adjust Scoring Values</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>
                    @foreach (VIMS.Web.Models.Measure m in Model.list)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(i => m.id)
                                @Html.LabelFor(i => m.measure) : 
                                @Html.DisplayFor(i => m.measure)
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                @Html.LabelFor(i => m.lastModified) :
                                @Html.DisplayFor(i => m.lastModified)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="range">
                            <td>
                                @Html.LabelFor(i => m.weight)
                                <br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(i => m.weight)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.LabelFor(i => m.zeroValue)
                                <br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(i => m.zeroValue)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.LabelFor(i => m.hundredValue)
                                <br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(i => m.hundredValue)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="range">
                            <td>
                                @Html.LabelFor(i => m.increment)
                                <br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(i => m.increment)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => m.rangeBased, "true", new { name=m.id.ToString()+ "Range"}) Range based incrememnt
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => m.rangeBased, "false", new { name = m.id.ToString() + "Range" }) Always incremented
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <hr />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="updateMeasures" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">SAVE</button>
                <button type="button" id="checkMeasures" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Check Values</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

The jQuery block looks like this:

```
//modal button click events to update/check measure values
$('#updateMeasures').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateScoring", "SendingReport", Model)',
        type: 'POST'
        })
    })
$('#checkMeasures').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckScoring", "SendingReport", Model)',
        type: 'POST'
    })
})
```

The model being passed in here has some of the properties populated but not others.  I was suspecting it had something to do with when the url is built since the model seems to be from the last time the page was posted.  How can I ensure the model referenced in the ajax function is refreshed when the page is rendered?

Comment: You're not sending any data in your ajax post.

Comment: @Saravana, I am passing the Model in the Url.Action statement.  That model has values that are not the defaults for some of the fields, so there is data being passed.  Is there a better way to pass that data?

Comment: What you're doing now will try to add the model properties as route values and append them to the URL as query string values. It will *not* POST them. Look at the rendered JQuery on your page to understand why. POST data is not sent in the URL.

Comment: @AntP, Ah!  Yes, I see that and that makes sense.  So how do I send this then?  In other words, I am clearly doing it wrong and now see the URL built, but how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to AntP for the comment as that was the difference I needed to know what to look for.  The magic that worked in the end was changing the jQuery so it did not rely entirely on the URL string but actually passed on data in the more traditional jQuery sense:

```
//modal button click events to update/check measure values
$('#updateMeasures').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateScoring", "SendingReport")',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        type: 'POST'
        })
    })
$('#checkMeasures').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckScoring", "SendingReport")',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        type: 'POST'
    })
})
```